# How to render nested array of jsx element in nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, jsx, nuxt3

In nuxt3 project I've array of `vnode` (using `jsx`) -

```js
<script lang="jsx" setup>
   const postContent = [
      <h1> title... </h1>
      <p> para... </p>
      <p> some text <span class='bold'> bold text </span> </p>
      :
      :
   ]
</script>
```

I tried to render -

```
<template>
   <div>
      {{ postContent }}
   </div>
</template>
```

but template doesn't render the html.

In `reactjs` I can achieve this easily :

```
export default function Post() {
   const postContent = [
      <h1> title... </h1>
      <p> para... </p>
      <p> some text <span class='bold'> bold text </span> </p>
      :
      :
   ]

   return <div>
     {postContent}
   </div>
}
```

How to render `array/nested array` of vnodes in `vue3/nuxt3` ?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching around on the web, I found how to render list of vnode -

```
<script lang="jsx" setup>
   const postContent = [
      <h1> title... </h1>
      <p> para... </p>
      <p> some text <span class='bold'> bold text </span> </p>
      :
      :
   ]

   const PostContentWrapper = <div class='wrapper'> {postContent} </div> 
</script>


<template>
   <div>
       <component v-bind:is="PostContentWrapper"></component>
   </div>
</template>
```